# Do we have a RxJavaComputationExpressions equivalent for Java Spring Reactor?

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, project-reactor

I am working with Java Reactor Mono type and I would like to have a very simple construct that would give me an 'ifThen'. I see that there is an implementation of this for RxJava [RxJavaComputationExpressions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaComputationExpressions) but unfortunately I am tied to Spring Reactor.

Does an implementation of something similar exist for Reactor or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no `ifThen` construct in `Mono`, you'll have to do the logical branching in a `flatMap` most probably.